# Cannot communicate serial port with different COM

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

I`m having a problem communicating with the serial port of Windows.

I have a Windows Service written in C.
This service is ready to listen requests from an application to communicate with a Pinpad. Pretty Simple.

The problem comes when the Pinpad's Com is assigned, sometimes it is assigned COM4,COM5, COM9 (these coms are working properly), so when the Pinpad's comm gets the COM10 or later, I get an error, and  I cannot communicate with the pinpad.  It sends me an error, this error is already defined, but I cannot figure what is the problem, cause in the function `CreateFileA`. Everything works perfect, I mean, it returns a handle, but in the next function: `GetCommState`, I get the error.

```
int srlOpen(char * szCOM)
{
    DCB dcbSrlParms;
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
    int inRetVal = P_SUCCESS;
    memset(&dcbSrlParms, 0x00, sizeof(dcbSrlParms));
    memset(&timeouts, 0x00, sizeof(timeouts));

if(inRetVal > P_ERROR)
{
    hSerial = CreateFileA(szCOM, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
    //hSerial = CreateFileA("COM21", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS,  
    //    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
    if(hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if(GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            inRetVal = ERR_PORT_NOT_FOUND;
        }
    }
}

if(inRetVal > P_ERROR)
{
    dcbSrlParms.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSrlParms);
    if(!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSrlParms))        
    {
        inRetVal = ERR_GET_PORT_CONFIG;
    }
}

if(inRetVal > P_ERROR)
{
    dcbSrlParms.BaudRate = CBR_19200;
    dcbSrlParms.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSrlParms.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcbSrlParms.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

    if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSrlParms))
    {
        inRetVal = ERR_SET_PORT_CONFIG;
    }
}

if(inRetVal > P_ERROR)
{
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = COMM_READ_INT_TMEOUT;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = COMM_READ_TOTAL_TIMEOUT;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = COMM_READ_TOTAL_MULTI;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = COMM_WRITE_TOTAL_TIMEOUT;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = COMM_WRITE_TOTAL_MULTI;

    if(!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts))
    {
        inRetVal = ERR_SET_TIMEOUT_CONFIG;
    }
}

pdebug (("inRetVal=%x", inRetVal));
return inRetVal;
}
```

Comment: How do you know CreateFileA is successful on the ComXX ports? It might fail and return something else than ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. If GetCommState fails, what does GetLastError tell?

Answer (score 1):

Invalid com port name.

A com port past `"COM9"` needs a different string format.
See [Specify Serial Ports Larger than COM9](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/115831)

```
srlOpen("COM9");         //OK
srlOpen("COM10");        //Not OK
srlOpen("\\\\.\\COM9");  //OK
srlOpen("\\\\.\\COM10"); //OK
```